# Using httpwebrequest to get image from website to byte[]

Tags: silverlight

I want to read the raw binary of a PNG file on a website and store it into a byte[], so far I have something like this:

```
            Uri imageUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/image.png");
            // Create a HttpWebrequest object to the desired URL.
            HttpWebRequest imgRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageUri);
                using (HttpWebResponse imgResponse = (HttpWebResponse)imgRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (BinaryReader lxBR = new BinaryReader(imgResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream lxMS = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        lnBuffer = lxBR.ReadBytes(1024);
                        while (lnBuffer.Length > 0)
                        {
                            lxMS.Write(lnBuffer, 0, lnBuffer.Length);
                            lnBuffer = lxBR.ReadBytes(1024);
                        }
                        lnFile = new byte[(int)lxMS.Length];
                        lxMS.Position = 0;
                        lxMS.Read(lnFile, 0, lnFile.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
```

but I can't use `GetResponse` on Silverlight because it is not Asynchronous (I think that's the reason) so instead I should be using `BeginGetResponse`, but I'm not completely clear on how to go about it. This is what I have so far:

```
                HttpWebResponse imgResponse = (HttpWebResponse)imgRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(WebComplete), imgRequest);

            using (imgResponse)
            {
                using (BinaryReader lxBR = new BinaryReader(imgResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    /*Same*/
                }
            }
```

and

```
        void WebComplete(IAsyncResult a)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)a.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(a);
        //...? Do I need something else here?
    }
```

can someone explain me a little bit how to use the `BeginGetResponse` property and how do I use the AsyncCallback.
Thanks!

Note:
I'm new to silverlight and I've been following tutorials and borrowing from other responses here on StackOverflow:
[(stackoverflow responce) what I need to do but not in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368115/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-to-pull-image-from-website-to-local-file)

[tutorial](http://wildermuth.com/2008/09/27/WebClient_vs_WebRequest_in_Silverlight_2)

[WebRequest_in_Silverlight](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/148451/330879.aspx)

is this valid Silverlight code?

```
HttpWebResponse imgResponse = (HttpWebResponse)imgRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(WebComplete), imgRequest);
```

Comment: Why a memory stream? What are you going to do with it once you have it?

Comment: I just need the bytes of the image to modify them and then create a BitmapImage out of them. If the memory stream don't simplify my work then I won't use it (to tell the truth I'm not sure what a memory stream is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working, want to post it here in case anyone needs it.

I need to get this image and then modify it (byte level) `Silverlight` didn't let me save the image directly to a `WriteableBitmap` and thus I had to get the image with a WebClient as a stream and then save it to a `byte[]`

this is how I get the image (I already have the specific Uri):

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
 wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
 wc.OpenReadAsync(uri)
```

so when the image is loaded the `wc_OpenReadCompleted` method is called and it does something like this:

```
int lengthInBytes = Convert.ToInt32(e.Result.Length);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(e.Result);

byte[] buffer = new byte[lengthInBytes];
using (br)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthInBytes; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = br.ReadByte();
    }
}
```

at the end the `buffer[]` has all the bytes of the image (what I wanted)
I'm sure there are better ways of doing this but this is working for me ! )

note: at some point I need to convert the byte[] to a BitmapImage (that was easier than expected):

```
        //imageInBytes is a byte[]

        if (imageInBytes != null)
        {
            MemoryStream rawBytesStream = new MemoryStream(imageInBytes);
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            img.SetSource(rawBytesStream);
            return img;
        }
```

I hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Oh and if anyone has any suggestion, please do post them!

Comment: Thanks for this - worked well for me.  One minor change, perhaps more efficient:  `buffer = br.ReadBytes(lengthInBytes);` instead of reading one byte at a time in loop

Answer (score 1):

Use the `OpenReadAsync` method of the `WebClient` object.  Attach to the `OpenReadCompleted` event of the `WebClient`. Use the `Stream` provided by the `Result` property of the event args.

Consider setting `AllowReadStreamBuffering`, this will fill the entire stream before raising the `OpenReadCompleted`.  In either case its likely you can use this stream to complete you real task rather than coping it into a MemoryStream.

Comment: so use WebClient instead of HttpWebRequest? I'll do a little research on those then. Thanks

Comment: Well it looks like I can't use HttpWebRequest anyways the HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse() gives me a runtime error

Comment: @david: You can use HttpWebRequest within Silverlight (internally thats what WebClient uses) however WebClient is far simpler in many cases.