# How to convert BitmapImage into byte array in silverlight4?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to convert the BitmapImage into byte array, but not getting the exact solution.
The `Image.Save()` method is not available in Silverlight Library.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

if you image source is in the project you can use this..

```
var uri = new Uri("/ReferencedAssembly;component/default.png", UriKind.Relative);
var streamInfo = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
var stream = streamInfo.Stream;
```

convert the stream to bytes array..

if image is one some other location

[Using httpwebrequest to get image from website to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407298/using-httpwebrequest-to-get-image-from-website-to-byte)

Regards

Comment: The image is from Database which is varbinary(max) type.

Comment: you want to save image to database in byte[]?

Comment: and image source is a resource in your application or it is hosted on some other site?

Comment: I am implemented the functionality which takes image by drag and drop.
User drags and drops the image in grid layout then i have to convert this image into byte[]. This image from user's local resource...

Comment: please clarify what will be the uri of local resource?