# Download images from a web server with AX 2009

Tags: image, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, ax

I'd like to download images from an web page and save them localy on my system and then connect them to an item in AX. Does anyone have an example how to download images form the internet with AX 2009?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to use the .Net Framework for this, calling the [System.Net.HttpWebRequest library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2009/05/19/how-to-cast-between-webrequest-and-httpwebrequest.aspx) from X++.

Once you have that, [converting the response to your image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368115/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-to-pull-image-from-website-to-local-file) will be a bit trickier, but only a little bit :)

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in the past. Download the file with .NET and save it on a shared folder on the filesistem, then return the full path to the newly created file. Then you can call to the DLL from AX as a "Reference" and if it succeed read the file from the path received, do whatever you need with it and finally delete (or run a periodic batch job to delete old files).

It worked fine for me that way.