# how to read image from url and save it into internal storage for windows 8 with c#

Tags: c#, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use httpwebrequest to pull image from website to local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368115/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-to-pull-image-from-website-to-local-file)

Let said, I have a picture a http://abc.com/image/abc.jpg and I would like to download it and save into the own storage in my windows 8 store application (not store into the picture library), so that my application can call and display the image and the image is not seem from picture library.

how to achieve the above task with c# ? code samples? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to let the browser cache this as that plumbing is already in place.

If you really want to pull this off, use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) is the class to use and [How to use httpwebrequest to pull image from website to local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368115/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-to-pull-image-from-website-to-local-file) seems to have a descent answer.

Comment: This code NO LONGER working for Windows 8 Store app aka metro app.

Comment: Yep, this shouldn't be a duplicate as it concerns a Windows Store App. You should find some useful code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786460/store-image-in-to-storagefile-from-image-control

Comment: Here is another approach: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/09f51999-b8c4-4d25-8c53-a03ae1884c16/windows-metro8-download-image-file-from-url-and-save-it-to-appdata