# Store image in to StorageFile from image control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, c#-5.0

how can i store image in to StorageFile from image control in windows store apps?
I'm using following link but that is not useful for me

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync(" ", new Uri(user.ProfilePicUrl), new RandomAccessStream());
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.createstreamedfileasync.aspx

I need clear solution for my problem. How can I do this?

Comment: how do you set image to image control ?

Comment: What do you mean, how exactly is that link not useful? What have you tried? How did that fail?

Comment: i set image to control from facebook profile pic url means some kind of web uri like https://survelydata.blob.core.windows.net/survelyimages/3e8e461ebe911d4ebb7f361f70f7daf3.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following method to save an image from an url to a file in `LocalFolder`:

```
public async Task<string> DownloadFileAsync(Uri uri, string filename)
{
    using (var fileStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
    {
        var webStream = await new HttpClient().GetStreamAsync(uri);
        await webStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        webStream.Dispose();
    }
    return (await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename)).Path;
}
```

Comment: sir i need how to get stream   from image control.....  or how to add into storage file ..

Comment: @SanjayPatel Didn't you say you're setting the image source to a web URL? Just pass the same URL to my method.

Comment: sir i got image from web url and then i want to save that image in to my cloud so that option i have to do image source to storage file..

Comment: @SanjayPatel The image is displayed in `Image` control? What did you set its source to? Just use the same url as the first parameter for my method.

Comment: It seems like `OpenStreamForWriteAsync` is not supported for Windows Store Apps!?

Comment: @user1954801 It's only supported for Windows Store apps since `IStorageFile` is not available on any other platform. It is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582147.aspx), though.