# Creating Image object using System.Drawing.Image.FromFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am trying to get the image dimensions of an image that user selects from list box. Image files are available on FTP server. I am displaying file names in a list box for users to select. Upon selection, I want to show the preview of image, for that I want to get dimensions so that I can resize it if i need to.

I am storing file name that is linked to currently selected list item into a string variable. I know that path on the server. I am using following code to create the Image object, but having no luck

```
try
{
     string dir = Session["currentUser"].ToString();
     System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("~/Uploads/"+dir+"/"+fName, true);     //ERROR here, it gives me file URL as error message!
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     lbl_Err.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

Not sure what is going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: So, what do you need? Do you get any exceptions, wrong values or don't you know how to get the values?

Comment: I'm not into asp.net, is something starting with ~ a valid path?

Comment: `FromFile` requires the `filename`, so I am giving a relative path (absolute path throws another error), but in exception it throws `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` and the message property of `ex` is `"~/Uploads/anemailtes/flower.png"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `Server.MapPath` to fetch the image from the server.
As follows

```
System.Drawing.Image img = 
      System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("Uploads/"+dir+"/"+fName), true);
```

You can use following as well

- Server.MapPath(".") returns the current physical directory of the file (e.g. aspx) being executed
- Server.MapPath("..") returns the parent directory
- Server.MapPath("~") returns the physical path to the root of the application
- Server.MapPath("/") returns the physical path to the root of the domain name (is not necessarily the same as the root of the application)

References
[Server.MapPath("."), Server.MapPath("~"), Server.MapPath(@"\"), Server.MapPath("/"). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)

Comment: thanks, it worked. Could you explain, because it gave me error when i used server.mappath earlier (must be used in-correctly )

Comment: Hi शेखर, How to get the image url in that From File method. For Ex: http://www.photos-public-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/baby-blue-micro-fiber-cloth-fabric-texture.jpg

Comment: @Vel you need to use [web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368115/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-to-pull-image-from-website-to-local-file)