# why should I do when Stream.CanSeek is false

Tags: c#, stream

I use this code to capture an image from IP Camera:

```
HttpWebRequest reqs = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + ip + snapshotCommand);
reqs.Method = "POST";
reqs.Timeout = 4000;
reqs.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
reqs.PreAuthenticate = true;

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)reqs.GetResponse();
if (resp != null)
{
    Stream stm = resp.GetResponseStream();
    img = new Bitmap(stm);
    stm.Close();
}
```

But stream threw an exception because `CanSeek` & `CanWrite` is false.
I tried many ways, for example `Copyto` (MemoryStream), but the problem still persists.
Would you please help me on that?

This is the code using MemoryStream:

```
Stream stm = resp.GetResponseStream(); 
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
stm.CopyTo(ms); 
ms.Position = 0;
```

And this "ms" for `ReadTimeout` & `WriteTimeout` threw:
Message "Timeouts are not supported on this stream." 
Because `canTimeout()` is false for MemoryStream too.

Finally I found this solution, and it works well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2368505/492628

Comment: I tried also Buffer Solution

Comment: show the code that copied to a `MemoryStream` and the error you got

Comment: Don't paste code into comments; such code is unreadable.  Please edit the question and paste the code there.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to copy the stream into a memory stream if it isn't seekable

Here's [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/230141/3364864) that might help.

Comment: I added my code to the question. This solution threw exception too.

Comment: The problem could be on the vendor's side in the webservice provider.

Comment: I capture `image` with snapshot command easily in Browser, but with reading stream in my code, there are these problem